# How to format using content from Ng-Repeat taken from Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is probably a really simple question (I am a bit new to AngularJS), but I have the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results" class="result">
   <div class="col-md-2 padding">
    ...
   </div>
</div>
```

For instance, after it fetches 4 result, I want the results to display on the next line.
Is there a way to keep a counter for the results fetched by ng-repeat? Or some indication to make the next result display on the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a break each fourth row (the plus 1 is since index starts at 0)

```
<br ng-if="($index+1)%4===0"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$index` inside it.

```
<div ng-if="$index == 3" class="col-md-2 padding">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[$index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) is built-in counter in ng-repeat, you can use it with [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive:

```
<br ng-if="$index === 3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the div tags to the span tags as otherwise by default it will be on a different line. Apart from that you can use the ng-if inorder to place a br tag

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="test">
    <span ng-repeat="result in results" class="result">
        <span class="col-md-2 padding">{{result}}
            <br ng-if="(($index+1) % 4) === 0" />
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oun9p6uz/)